# Clone/append large HTML blocks in jQuery but change inner vars?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large HTML block that I need to clone and append based on a selectbox value. It works as is, but instead of using the actual HTML block I wanted to know if I can use clone and dynamically change certain content.

HTML:

```
<select id="guestNum">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<div class="group-sizing">
    <div class='form-group row border'>
        <div class='inner'>
            <h3>Guest 1 Welcome</h3>
            <div class='select'>
                <select class='form-control' id='guest1'>
                    <option value='New' selected>New</option>
                    <option value='Existing'>Existing</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='inner'>
            <h3>Date</h3>
            <div class='date'>
                <div class='inner'>
                    <p>April 1</p>
                    <p>No Guests</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var comDate = $("<div class='inner'>\
                    <p>April 1</p>\
                    <p>No Guests</p>\
                </div>\
                <div class='inner'>\
                    <p>April 2</p>\
                    <p>Guests Welcome</p>\
                </div>");
$("#guestNum").change(function(){
    var count = $(this).val();
    $(".group-sizing .form-group:gt("+(count-1)+")").remove();
    for (var i = $(".group-sizing .form-group").length; i < count; i++){
        $("<div class='form-group row border'>\
        <div class='inner'>\
            <h3>Guest " + (i+1) + " Welcome</h3>\
            <div class='select'>\
                <select class='form-control' id='guest" + (i+1) + "'>\
                    <option value='New' selected>New</option>\
                    <option value='Existing'>Existing</option>\
                </select>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
        <div class='inner'>\
            <h3>Date</h3>\
            <div class='date'>" + comDate + "</div>\
        </div>\
    </div>").appendTo(".group-sizing");
    }
});
```

Since I already include the blocks of code on the page, I want to know if I can just clone what I have, change the necessary values and then do it that way instead of having all the HTML in the js again.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csv8x6xz/)

Comment: Have you thought about using a framework for this, like handlebars?  I'm not a strong believer in using frameworks all the time, but in this case it would simplify this a lot.

Comment: It's literally for a single page that will be taken down after April 1 so a framework is probably overkill.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't probably exactly what you want but heres an example of how you can clone html, and insert variables inside.

Hopefully this will guide you in the right direction.

This could be a page too, for simplicity I just set it to display none.

```
<div id="template" style="display:none;">
  <div class="group-sizing">
    <div class="form-group row border">
      <div class="inner">
        <h3>Guest {{id}} Welcome</h3>
        <div class="select">
          <select class="form-control" id="guest1">
            <option value="New" selected>New</option>
            <option value="Existing">Existing</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="inner">
        <h3>Date</h3>
        <div class="date">
          <div class="inner">
            <p>{{date}}</p>
            <p>No Guests</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then create a JS function to scrape the html for the `{{}}`

```
function findHandleBars(html) {
  var results = [], re = /{{([^}]+)}}/g, text;

  while(text = re.exec(html)) {
    results.push(text[1]);
  }

  return results;

}
```

I created a simple 'guest' array

```
var guests = [
   {
      "id": "1",
      "date": "April 1"
   },
   {
      "id": "2",
      "date": "April 2"
   },
   {
      "id": "3",
      "date": "April 3"
   }
];
```

Define

```
var template = $('#template').prop('innerHTML');
```

Call the findHandleBars method and set the array to a variable

```
var results = findHandleBars(template);
```

Then loop through the guests and loop through the handleBars found and replace with variable

```
for(i=0; i< guests.length; i++){

var n = template;

for(i=0; i< guests.length; i++){
  var n = template;

  for(b=0; b<results.length; b++){
    var n = n.replace('{{'+results[b]+'}}', guests[i][results[b]]);
  }

  $('#body').append(n);

};
```

Here is the fiddle...https://jsfiddle.net/csv8x6xz/15/

Comment: Sorry, I'm not fully understanding. It's just printing three blocks of Guest 1 Welcome.

Comment: My bad I messed up the n.replace.  Check it out now

Comment: Would it not be better to just count the number of guests during findHandleBars? That way you get current count and could skip the guests array?

Comment: You could do whatever you want.  My intention was to show how someone could clone large html blocks, change the inner variables, then append them.  Like your question asked.  I wasn't trying to write your whole thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery`s [clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) function. Then use

`newguest = $('.group-sizing').eq(0).clone();
 newguest.find('span','.guest-welcome').html(i);` <<< To change specific element in cloned element.

Tested in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csv8x6xz/18/).

HTML

```
<select id="guestNum">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<div class="group-sizing">
    <div class='form-group row border'>
      <div class='inner'>
      <h3 class='guest-welcome'>Guest <span>1</span> Welcome</h3>
        <div class='select'>
          <select class='form-control' id='guest1'>
            <option value='New' selected>New</option>
            <option value='Existing'>Existing</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='inner'>
        <h3>Date</h3>
        <div class='date'>
          <div class='inner'>
            <p>April 1</p>
            <p>No Guests</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#guestNum").change(function(){

  var count = $(this).val();
  var len = $('.group-sizing').length;
  var newguest;
  var remove = true;
  for(var i = count; i > 0; i--)
  {
    newguest = $('.group-sizing').eq(0).clone();
    newguest.find('span','.guest-welcome').html(i);
    $(this).after(newguest);
    if(remove)
    {
      $('.group-sizing').eq(0).nextAll().remove();
      remove = false;
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: That for loop is an infinite loop waiting to happen.... Why don't you set the for loop to for(i=0;i<count;i++)  then  newguest.find('span','.guest-welcome').html(count);  since you are grabbing the value from the select box anyways

Comment: I'm saying its an infinite loop waiting to happen.... meaning why on earth are you looping through it backwards(not saying it's an infinite loop currently), one inexperienced JS developer and that things runs forever.  Maybe you should think of a more clever way to change the count to work instead of having to reverse your loop lol.  Theres at least 5 different ways you aren't thinking of